# Creating a function that depends on an arbitrary function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, derivative

How would I create a function in Mathematica that depends on an arbitrary function? For instance, if I were to make a function that takes the derivative of a function (I know this example is built into Mathematica, go with me on this), this would involve translating the variable of the arbitrary function. Is it possible to do this?
What I am really trying to do is make a function that takes the fractional derivative of a function. There is a way to do this via integration, but I would like to use the limit definition of the fractional derivative.

Comment: Look in the documentation for higher-order functions.

Comment: show an example of what youve tried. also you may want to try mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Taking a function

```
f = (x + 2) (x^2 + 1) x (x - 1) (x - 2);
```

Here is a function that takes a derivative of a function

```
g[f_] := D[f, x]
```